# Referencing column names alongside values in python when generating multiple txt files

Tags: python

I'm building a program to generate input data for an old piece of renewable energy modeling software.

So I have a dataframe that I need to **convert to multiple txt files**.

```
                     WF1     WF2     WF3  ...    WF41      WF42     WF43
Time                                      ...                           
WIND_2007_1_1_p1     0.0  0.3518  3.1120  ...  22.064  128.0884  14.1040
WIND_2007_1_1_p2     0.0  0.1876  2.4675  ...  23.975  127.8132  11.8336
```

I need to iterate through every value in each row starting at WF1 and **add the column name in front of it** before starting a new line and moving on to the next file (every row becomes a new file). Then I need to close the file and open a new one. **File names should be the first column** WIND_2007_1_1_p1 for example. 
The text file output should look like this.

```
GENERATORS
WF1, 0.265586243238
WF2, 0.30197708804
WF3, 4.114375794452
WF4, 5.490531222528
WF5, 0.12281958414
WF6, 3.00855824352
WF7, 7.66010262368
WF8, 12.3705585070848
```

**Many thanks!**

Comment: is ```Time``` index columns ?

Comment: @Sushanth Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, `Time` is an index column apply [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) would yield,

`[{"WIND_2007_1_1_p1": {"WF1: 0.0, "WF2": 0.3}..]`

```
for index, value in df.to_dict(orient='index').items():
    with open(index, "w") as f:
        f.writelines("\n".join([k + "," + str(v) for k, v in value.items()]))
```